# Flash OSX Projector - Fullscreen Video Crashing (black screen)

Tags: flash, video, crash, fullscreen, projector

First up... I've searched Google and Stack Overflow but I've not come across anything that can solve my problem.
It has been suggested to other dev's with a similar-but-not-the-same problem that `flvControl.fullScreenTakeOver = false;` could be the issue, but that doesn't seem to be the case with me.

Right now to the problem...
I have been given a flash file to update and I'm running into trouble with fullscreen video.
The flash file exports an OSX projector that auto runs in fullscreen.
The projector displays a series of thumbnails and the user can click on one to view an associated video file.

When the file is first run it scales up the stage with the following code:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Then when the user clicks on a thumbnail it runs the below code, but displays a black screen. (from my research online this is an indicator that the video component has crashed).

```
import fl.video.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
import flash.events.FullScreenEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;


var flvSource:String = (MovieClip(this.parent).theNextVideo);
var flvControl:FLVPlayback = display;
var videoHDWidth:Number = 1920;
var videoHDHeight:Number = 1080;
var videoRegWidth:Number = 1280;
var videoRegHeight:Number = 720;

flvControl.align = VideoAlign.TOP_LEFT;
flvControl.scaleMode = VideoScaleMode.MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO;
flvControl.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
flvControl.setSize(videoHDWidth, videoHDHeight);

flvControl.source = flvSource;

stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, videoHDWidth, videoHDHeight);
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

signBack_mc.useHandCursor = true;
signBack_mc.buttonMode = true;
signBack_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backButtonHandler);
signBack_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, backButtonRollOverHandler);
signBack_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, backButtonRollOutHandler);
```

I have discovered that when the projector initially launches to fullscreen mode, if I press ESC on my keyboard to return the projector to a windowed mode I can then click on a thumbnail (it jumps to FS mode) and play the video, close the video (it jumps to Window Mode), click another thumbnail (it jumps to FS mode) and play that video, but it just doesn't work when the projector is in fullscreen mode and then clicking into fullscreen.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?
I've not done anything similar to this in the past so I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Thank you!,
Shane

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this issue. 
The problem was not to do with going fullscreen, but that the video component was initialised before the related bits and pieces were ready causing it to crash.